# Argument of type 'Function | FieldValue' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Tags: deno, denodb

I create a user model:

```
class UserModel extends Model {

    static table = 'users'
    static timestamps = true

    static fields = {
        id: { primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
        firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
        lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
        username: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        password: DataTypes.STRING,
        birthday: DataTypes.DATE,
        phoneNumber: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    }
}
```

while I compare the existent user password with the new one:

```
async signin(user: Pick<User, "username" | "password">){
        const { username, password } = user;

    const existentUser = await UserModel.where('username', username).first()

    if (!existentUser) throw new CustomErrorHandler(Status.NotFound, "User does not exist")

    const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(password, existentUser.password); // Argument of type 'Function | FieldValue' // is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
 // Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
}
```

I got this ts error:

```
Argument of type 'Function | FieldValue' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I can fix it by forcing the type using :

```
const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(password, <string>existentUser.password);
```

but I'm looking for another solution. Is there another approach to convert returned Model by `first()` to `User` interface or something else?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use typed fields on your models, you'll want to set up [Model Records](https://eveningkid.com/denodb-docs/docs/api/model-records) by duplicating the fields, like so:

```typescript
class UserModel extends Model {
    static table = 'users'
    static timestamps = true

    static fields = {
        id: { primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
        firstName: DataTypes.STRING,
        lastName: DataTypes.STRING,
        username: DataTypes.STRING,
        email: DataTypes.STRING,
        password: DataTypes.STRING,
        birthday: DataTypes.DATE,
        phoneNumber: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    }

    id!: string;
    firstName!: string;
    lastName!: string;
    username!: string;
    email!: string;
    password!: string;
    birthday!: Date;
    phoneNumber!: number;
}
```

Also, it looks like `/x/denodb` doesn't set up generic return types on the model functions. I was able to get your example to typecheck by only casting the return of `first()` to `UserModel`. Here's the version of `signin()` that I was running myself:

```typescript
async function signin(user: Pick<UserModel, "username" | "password">){
    const { username, password } = user;

    const existentUser = <UserModel> await UserModel.where('username', username).first();

    if (!existentUser) throw new Error("User does not exist")

    const isPasswordCorrect = bcrypt.compareSync(password, existentUser.password);
    if (!isPasswordCorrect) throw new Error("Bad password")
}
```

Needing to cast to the correct model seems like something that can be improved in `/x/denodb`. I'll see if the project accepts a PR, but for now the above seems clean enough :)